# Codeigniter use form validation for variable

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I've read somewhere that is possible to use Codeigniter's Form Validation also for my own variables and not only for form's inputs.

For example I'd like to validate a url to say if it is valid but not retrieving it using POST or GET from a form.

Do you know how or have a link?

Comment: Where did you read it? What's the point of loading a form validation library and use it with another meaning? why not using a dedicate library/helper/function/piece of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PHP5 above version,you can do this

```
function validdate_urls($str) {

    if(!filter_var($str, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
    {
        $this->validation->set_message('validate_urls', 'URL Invalid');
        return 0;
    }else {
        return TRUE;
    }

}
```

And call it in your validation rules :-

```
$rules['link'] = "callback_validate_urls";
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for are the callbacks of the Form Validation Class in CodeIgniter - read [the user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks) for an in-depth explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can via `set_data()` method, Here you go.

```
$this->form_validation->set_data(array(
        'cartId'    =>  $cartId
));

$this->form_validation->set_rules('cartId', 'Card ID', 'trim|required|is_natural_no_zero');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
    echo 'Invalid: ' . validation_errors();
} else {
    echo 'Valid';
}
```